# How to tidy up a character column?

Tags: r, tidyverse

**What I have:**

```
test_df <- data.frame(isolate=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5),label=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),alignment=c("--at","at--","--at","--at","a--","acg","a--","a--", "agg"))

> test_df
  isolate label alignment
1       1     1   --at
2       2     1   at--
3       3     1   --at
4       4     1   --at
5       1     2   a--
6       2     2   acg
7       3     2   a--
8       4     2   a--
9       5     2   agg
```

**What I want**:

I'd like to explode the alignment field into two columns, position and character:

```
> test_df
  isolate label aln_pos  aln_char
1       1     1       1  -
2       1     1       2  -
3       1     1       3  a
4       1     1       4  t
...
```

Not all alignments are the same length, but all alignments with the same label have the same length.

**What I've tried**:

I was thinking I could use `separate` to first make each position have its own column, then use `gather` turn those columns into key value pairs. However, I haven't been able to get the separate part right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned `tidyr::gather`, you could try this:

```
test_df <- data.frame(isolate=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5),
                      label=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                      alignment=c("--at","at--","--at","--at","a--","acg","a--","a--", "agg"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)

test_df %>% 
  mutate(alignment = strsplit(alignment,"")) %>% 
  unnest(alignment)
```

Comment: this does it. then piping to `%>% group_by(label, isolate) %>% mutate(align_pos=row_number())` gets the positions as well.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use indexing along with creation of a list with `strsplit` like this.

```
# make variable a character vector
test_df$alignment <- as.character(test_df$alignment)
# get list of individual characters
myList <- strsplit(test_df$alignment, split="")
```

then build the data.frame

```
# construct data.frame
final_df <- cbind(test_df[rep(seq_len(nrow(test_df)), lengths(myList)),
                          c("isolate", "label")],
                  aln_pos=sequence(lengths(myList)),
                  aln_char=unlist(myList))
```

Here, we take the first two columns of the original data.frame and repeat the rows using `rep` with a vector input in its second argument telling it how many times to repeat the corresponding value in its first argument. The number of times is calculated with `lengths`. The second argument of `cbind` is a call to `sequence` taking the same `lengths` output. this produces counts from 1 to the corresponding length. The third argument is the unlisted character values.

this returns

```
head(final_df, 10)
    isolate label aln_pos aln_char
1         1     1       1        -
1.1       1     1       2        -
1.2       1     1       3        a
1.3       1     1       4        t
2         2     1       1        a
2.1       2     1       2        t
2.2       2     1       3        -
2.3       2     1       4        -
3         3     1       1        -
3.1       3     1       2        -
```